# How can I save the values from fields in a Windows Forms GUI to a file, and then restore them?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, streamreader, streamwriter

I want to load content stored in a file, into the fields of a WinForms GUI.

My approach right now: I've got a streamwriter which writes each text box to a line in a .txt file. I have the streamreader setup but i have no idea how to get it to load each line into seperate text boxes. For example: Task1_name (line 1) and task1_desc (line 2) need to be in seperate text boxes, how could i get it to load into the boxes?

Thanks

Code:

Save Button:

```
void Save_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
        sw.WriteLine(task1_name.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(task1_desc.Text);
        sw.WriteLine(task1_date.Value);
        sw.WriteLine(task1_check.Checked);
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Load Button:

```
void Load_buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to load?", "Load",     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
        sr.Close();
    }           
}
```

Comment: Are you tied to use a plain text file? Consider storing your information in Xml which would make it easy to query the data and assign it to each desired control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add every line into a List and access them by index:

```
//...
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}

task1_name.Text = lines[0];
task1_desc.Text = lines[1];
//...
```

Comment: Is there anyway of changing this so i can have date/time and a checkbox as well?

Comment: Well you just need to cast or parse the string you saved to your text file. If you want easy data type handling Cheesos answers is really the best way. Basically it's the only sensible way to implement something like this. I just put my answer here because it will do exactly what you asked but the best solution is Cheesos answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use XML Serialization.  It would look something like this:

```
public class MySettings 
{
  public String name {get;set;}
  public String name {get;set;}
  public DateTime date {get;set;}
  public bool checked {get;set;}
}

void Save() 
{
  var s = new MySettings 
  {
    name = this.task1_Name.Text,
    desc = this.task1_Desc.Text,
    date = this.task1_Date.Value,
    checked = this.task1_Check.Checked
  };
  var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
  using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
  {
      using (var tw = new StreamWriter(fs, new UTF8Encoding()))
      {
          var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
          ns.Add("", "");
          ser.Serialize(tw, this, ns);
      }
  }
}
```

And to load it would look like this:

```
    static MySettings Load()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MySettings));
        MySettings settings = null;

        try
        {
            using (var s = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                settings = (MySettings) ser.Deserialize(s);
                // optionally validate here
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read settings. " + ex1.Message,
                            "error");
            settings = null;
        }
        return settings;
    }
```

And then of course resetting your form would be like this:

```
 var settings = Load();
 this.task1_Name.Text = settings.name;
 this.task1_Desc.Text = settings.desc;
 this.task1_Date.Value = settings.date;
 this.task1_Check.Checked = settings.checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the lines and populate the form in the same order as you wrote them:

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);
    task1_name.Text = sr.ReadLine();
    task1_desc.Text = sr.ReadLine();
    task1_date.Value = DateTime.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    task1_checked.Checked = bool.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    sr.Close();
}
```